# sum of dictionary values in python 3

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

I have the following dictionary:

```
dic= {'I-setosa': 8, 'I-versicolor': 2, 'I-virginica': 0}
```

How can i find the sum of the keys? In `Python 2` I could do the following:

```
sum(dic.values())
```

Is there any other way than this? I tried using `dic.values()` and find the sum of that list, but it is too lengthy.

Comment: It does work in Python 3.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I wrote the question other way. Just edited it.

Comment: What does "too lengthy" mean? It's just three elements! Btw, it's not a list.

Comment: Not only does this still work in Python 3, it's *better* than it used to be, because it doesn't make a pointless list of values. In Python 2, `sum(dic.itervalues())` or `sum(dic.viewvalues())` would have been the way to avoid the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> sum(dic.values())
> ```
>
> Is there any other way than this?

Sure. Infinitely many. But why are you asking? That's **the** right way to do it.

Comment: For the record, this doesn't work if in IPython with the `--pylab` flag, or if you've executed `from pylab import *`, because both of these overwrite the base `sum` with `numpy`'s `sum`, which returns the `dict_values` iterator when executing `sum(dic.values())`.